How to update first layer weights?
I’m trying to make a neural network without using any deep learning library that recognizes numbers in the mnist database. Its structure is: 784 input neurons (for the 784 pixels in the number images), 10 hidden neurons (only 1 hidden layer) and 10 output neurons. There’s 10 biases for the hidden layer.
I think I know how to update the last layer weights, but not the first ones as the last layer’s weights influence the result. I dont know how to update biases neither. If I made any mistake in the last layer update, please let me know.
Here’s the code:
#forward propagation
def forward(inp, w1, w2, biases):
    hidsRes = []
    outRes = []

    for i in range(len(w1)):
        n = np.dot(inp, w1[i])

        n += biases[i]
        n = relu(n)

        hidsRes.append(n)

    for i in range(len(w2)):
        n = np.dot(hidsRes, w2[i])

        outRes.append(n)

    return softmax(outRes)

#backpropagation
def back(avgResult, w1, w2, lr):
    for i, w in enumerate(w2):
        w2[i] += lr * avgResult[i] #I only update the last layer based on the average error of each neuron

def train(inps, hids, outs, randomWeightDiff, batchs, gens, lr):
    w1, w2, b = initNn(inps, hids, outs, randomWeightDiff)

    #loading the mnist dataset
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = getData()

    for gen in range(gens):
        errors = []

        x_train, y_train = shuffle(x_train, y_train)
        
        for batch in range(batchs):  
            prediction = forward(tolist(x_train[batch].tolist()), w1, w2, b)
            y = y_train[batch]

            target = [0 if i != y else 1 for i in range(10)]

            errors.append([prediction[i] - target[i] for i in range(10)])

        print(errors)

        avg = [sum([errors[i][j] for j in range(len(errors))]) / 10 for i in range(10)]

        back(avg, w1, w2, lr)
        print("Generation {gen} \n" + f"{avg}")

train(784, 10, 10, 2, 100, 1000, 0.01)

I tried simulating a lot of neural networks and mutating the best ones, but it was too slow and it was not working.
By the way, I didn’t learn advanced maths yet.

I think your biggest error is updating weights with the model's error and not the error's derivatives. It's not backpropagation. To update a parameter of the network you must compute the derivative of the error regarding the parameter (with chain rule for deeper layers) and apply it to the weight using gradient descent technique.
Minimizing error is a little like stepping down from the hill. Gradients inform you where you should make the next step to descend the step maximally. You need information about the slope of the path around you. Using average error by you can be compared here to looking for a way down knowing only the mere altitude, it's not very helpful.
I keep my fingers crossed for your further steps :)

Thanks for the answer! After reading some code examples, i've learned that:
To get the gradient of the last layer, I have to mutliply the error by the derivative of the activation function of the output with respect to the output. Then, I can get the gradient of layer n by multiplying the gradient of the previous layer by the weights of layer n and then multiplying that with the derivative of the activation function with respect to the activation of layer n. Is this correct?
